# Django Query: How to order posts by amount of upvotes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I'm currently working on a website (with Django), where people can write a story, which can be upvoted by themselves or by other people. Here are the classes for Profile, Story and Upvote:

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)


class Story(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author")
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)


class Upvote(models.Model):
  profile = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="upvoter")
  story = models.ForeignKey('Story', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="upvoted_story")
  upvote_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

As you can see, Upvote uses two foreign keys to store the upvoter and the related story. Now I want to make a query which gives me all the stories, sorted by the amount of upvotes they have. I've tried my best to come up with some queries myself, but it's not exactly what I'm searching for.

This one doesn't work at all, since it just gives me all the stories in the order they were created, for some reason. Also it contains duplicates, although I want them to be grouped by story.

```
hot_feed = Upvote.objects.annotate(upvote_count=Count('story')).order_by('-upvote_count')
```

This one kind of works. But if I'm trying to access a partical story in my template, it just gives me back the id. So I'm not able to fetch the title, author and content from that id, since it's just an integer, and not an object.

```
hot_feed = Upvote.objects.values('story').annotate(upvote_count=Count('story')).order_by('-upvote_count')
```

Could someone help me out with finding the query I'm searching for?

Comment: Please remove all fields that are not relevant to this question (we like to have _minimal_ examples).

Comment: Will do! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying from the wrong model, you here basically fetch `Upvote`s ordered by the number of stories, or something similar.

But your probaby want to retrieve `Story`s by the number of upvotes, so you need to use `Story` as "queryset root", and annotate it with the number of upvotes:

```
Story.objects.annotate(
    upvote_count=Count('upvoted_story')
).order_by('-upvote_count')
```

I think the `related_name` of your `story` is however a bit "*misleading*". The `related_name` is the name of the relation "in reverse", so probably a better name is `upvotes`:

```
class Upvote(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.Profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='upvotes'
    )
    story = models.ForeignKey(
        'Story',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='upvotes'
    )
    upvote_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In that case the query is:

```
Story.objects.annotate(
    upvote_count=Count('upvotes')
).order_by('-upvote_count')
```

Comment: I must have gotten really confused by wheter I should fetch for Upvotes or Stories. Anyways, this works! You really helped me out, thanks a lot! However I have one more question, if you don't mind. In that query you count 'upvoted_story', but how does it know if a story is upvoted or not, since that's stored in a different model? And then in the end you order by 'upvote_count'. Where does it get that information from?

Comment: Oh, no okay, I get it. You worked with the related_name to construct the query, right?

Comment: @FrederikVanclooster: `'upvoted_story'` is the `related_name` of the `ForeignKey`, so it will, in the database, perform a `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY`, and count the number of *related* upvotes. We store that count as `upvote_count` (this is th part before the `=` in the `.annotate(..)`. This is thus an integer, and we sort that in a descending way.

Comment: Yup, I understand it now! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @FrederikVanclooster: indeed. It uses the name of the `ForeignKey`.